# Apache drill showing datatype 'ANY'

Tags: hdfs, apache-drill

I created a view 'names' over a csv file in dfs. I tried using describe statement:

```
describe dfs.root.`names`
```

Here is my create view statement:

```
create view dfs.root.`names` as select id,name,city from dfs.root.`names.csv`
```

In the output, in the data type column I get data type for all columns as 'ANY'

Here are my csv file contents:

```
id,name,city
1,shrinivas,pune
2,harshal,morgaon
3,nikhil,chiplun
4,ravinder,chandigarh
```

the `extractHeader` parameter in my configuration is set to true

Any ideas on how to get the exact data type in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the datatype of each during view creation:

```
create view dfs.root.`names` as select cast(id as smallint) ID,cast(name as varchar) NAME,cast(city as varchar) CITY from dfs.root.`names.csv`
```

Comment: I was reluctant to use cast, but I guess there's no other way.. Thank you for the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, [DESCRIBE](https://drill.apache.org/docs/describe/) does not support tables created in a file system. The create view statement does not explore the actual schema of the query’s table(s); it only parses and keeps the query.

Can you please try using typeOf(columnName) instead like:

```
select typeof(id), typeof(name), typeof(city) from dfs.root.`names.csv`;
```

Comment: It's working in a way, but now it is showing all columns as varchar